# Puppet not creating grafana

Tags: puppet, grafana

When trying to run this code in my puppet-server - it complains on the port TCP 3000.

> Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Grafana_datasource[prometheus]: Could not evaluate: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3000 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000)

```
class { 'grafana':
    cfg => {
    app_mode     => 'production',
   },
     database => {
        type => 'mysql',
        host => '127.0.0.1:3306',
        name => 'grafana',
        user => 'root',
        type => '',
     },
     users => {
       allow_sign_up => false,
     },
}

grafana_datasource { 'Prometheus':
    grafana_url      => 'http://localhost:3000',
    grafana_user     => 'admin',
    grafana_password => 'grafanapw',
    type             => 'prometheus',
    url              => 'http://prom-ip:9090',
    access_mode      => 'proxy',
    is_default       => true,
    require          => Class['grafana'],
}
```

If I try to add this code into the class { 'grafana':} 
It stops complaining - but no datasource is created

```
class { 'grafana':
    cfg  => {
      server => {
        http_port => 8080,
      }
    },
    database => { 
    ...
    },
}
```

Overall the main issue is that grafana won't be created with a working datasource & dashboard(not shown here)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOz01.png

Comment: Please share the relevant output so that we can assist.

Comment: A picture has been provided.

Comment: Do not post images of text output.  Copy and paste the relevant text itself.

Comment: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Grafana_datasource[prometheus]: Could not evaluate: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3000 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000)

Answer (score 0):

Grafana bind defaults to 3000. To use port 8080 you need to either give the Grafana binary:

```
    $ sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/grafana-server
```

Comment: Well the problem is that the upper code does not work - something I want to...
But if I specify the `http_port: 8080` it makes it possible to go use grafana

Now: ip-grafana:8080
Want: ip-grafana:3000

Do I have to use nginx or something for reverse proxy?

Comment: Do you tried put the grafana in port 3000?

`class { 'grafana':
    cfg  => {
      server => {
        http_port => 3000,
      }
    },
    database => { 
    ...
    },
}`